# How to intercept ctrl + c command in python running in cygwin

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin

I run python script inside a cygwin shell but I'm not able to intercept <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> command.

This is my python script:

```
#!/cygdrive/c/python27/python.exe -u
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, signal_handler)

print('Press Ctrl+C')
input()
```

Also using a try/catch method still not working

```
#!/cygdrive/c/python27/python.exe -u
try:
    input()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Interrupted')
```

but non of these handler works with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> command. The Cygwin version is 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) and I'm using python 2.7. What's wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are using the windows versions of python from a cygwin shell. This does not work as expected. You can install python2 and one of several different python3 versions with the cygwin setup program. At the same time, upgrade your cygwin installation to the latest version 3.0.6(0.338/5/3). Your version is years out of date. Just a reminder: Python 2.7 reaches end-of-life on 2020-Jan-01 (less than 8 months). All new work should use Python 3.6 or later.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in the MSYS environment (https://www.msys2.org/) in its mingw64 terminal. I was finally able to fix the issue using the `winpty` tool:

```
winpty python3 my_python_script.py
```

This way signal handlers work as expected. I'm just not sure if the `winpty` tool is available in your cygwin distribution as well.